# PHP MySQL INSERT query not inserting to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I can't figure out why my INSERT query is failing. I've double checked the query in phpMyAdmin and it works fine, yet when it's put into the PHP it fails.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])){

    //Insert booking to the database
    $InsertQuery = DB::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO booking (`StartDate`, `EndDate`, `UserId`, `ItemId`) VALUES (
        '{$_POST['startdate']}', '{$_POST['enddate']}', {$_POST[currentuser]}, {$_POST[itemid]}");
    print_r($InsertQuery);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="MakeABooking1.php" method="post">
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemid" value=" <?php echo $ItemId ?> "> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="currentuser" value=" <?php echo $currentUser ?> "> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="startdate" value=" <?php echo $bookFrom ?> "> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="enddate" value=" <?php echo $bookTo ?> "> </td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="create" value="Book"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </form>
```

Doing `print_r($InsertQuery);` displays the following:

> DB Object ( [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object ( ) [_query:DB:private]
>   => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO booking (`StartDate`, `EndDate`, `UserId`, `ItemId`) VALUES ( ' 2015-03-26 ',
>   ' 2015-03-31 ', 48 , 8 ) [_error:DB:private] => 1
>   [_results:DB:private] => Array ( ) [_count:DB:private] => 0 )

When copying the query from the print_r it is valid and creates a booking. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's in prepared mode. Now you have to try to execute after if.

Comment: Error checking? What's in the error logs?

Comment: Not executing the query. *Mornin' Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: I sometimes suffer from a total lack of execution myself @Fred-ii- *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: Not by wearing a medieval facemask I hope @JayBlanchard

Comment: Heh....brings to mind a favorite cheesy movie of mine @Fred-ii-

Comment: @JayBlanchard Where should I be looking for these error logs? Sorry, I'm new to all this

Comment: @JayBlanchard [What am I not grasping?...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29301492/)

Comment: All you're doing is `print_r($InsertQuery);` You need to execute it. Here, read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: *Well...* no further word from the OP, *moving on Sam* @JayBlanchard

Comment: @Fred-ii- I haven't had to execute any of my other queries, I used a tutorial to create a DB class which, as far as I'm aware, has the execute function within it? `if($this->_query->execute()) {
                                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out I just had an error in my SQL query, I was missing a ) after my list of VALUES. Not gonna lie, feel pretty dumb! Thank you for all of your suggestions.